# What are possible causes of a row in a SQL query result breaking into 2 rows instead of 1 row when brought into excel?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This doesn't happen often, but I have had this happen a few times when getting data from SQL Server Management Studio, where a row result will not all be on one single row.  Is this a result of poor database management or is it an issue with the way I am querying the server?

[You can see this particular line splitting into a second row when executed as text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHl2R.png)

[SQL Server executing as grid, where it appears to all be in a single row, and not broken at the 'SPC' column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2P8y.png)

[data results in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOvRH.png)

Comment: That behaviour is usually caused by a (non printable) "dirty" character at the end of a column, which is handled by SQL Server but interpreted as a line break by Excel. Maybe a copy/paste by a user inserted that character

Comment: Excel does weird stuff. Try doing "Import from Text" and specifying the column separators

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to the Newline('\n') character at an end or somewhere in the text column.